# qws parameter for Qt-embedded is not working

Tags: qt

I created a basic Qt application for Qt-embedded but when I executed that application in my target platform using the -qws parameter then an error message always appear, please see below,

`#./test_app -qws

QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused

No Qt for Embedded Linux server appears to be running.
If you want to run this program as a server,
add the "-qws" command-line option.
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted`

Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Is "test_app" linked again qt/embedded?
- What print "strace ./test_app"
- Have you played with LD_DEBUG-environmnt variable?